# Start activity and change the widget image button on click in android

Tags: android-widget

I want to start an activity and change the widget image button on click.
How can i do it? I don't know it properly.After much googling, it still is not solvable.

Comment: what you try so far? any code where you have errors?

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to create a button.
I will use the programmatic way:
Source to create the button in one Activity class:

```
//making the container for the button  
TableLayout.LayoutParams tableParams = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT, WRAP_CONTENT);
TableLayout tableLayout = new TableLayout(this);
tableLayout.setLayoutParams(tableParams);

//making the button
Button button = new Button(this);

//making the class what will handler the click
button.setOnClickListener(new ClassWithBehavior());

//set the color of button state1
button.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#ff00ff"), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);

//adding the button at the container
tableLayout.addView(button);
```

source of the ClassWithBehavior:

```
private class ClassWithBehavior implements View.OnClickListener {
    public void onClick(View button) {
        //set the color of button state2
        this.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#00ff00"), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
    }
}
```

create a new activity:

```
//need have first a Intent before change of the activity   
Intent i = new Intent(a, Activity2.class);

//share data between old_activity and the new_activity
i.putExtra("id_tag_name_of_the_data_from_activity1_to_activity2",data);

//launch the new activity
this.startActivity(i);
```

Remember that every activity have its own variables, and views, if you not pass the state of button or the color at the new activity, this wouldn't have these info.